# Microsoft Fluent Design transparency

Tags: transparency, html, web-platforms, fluent-design

How to create a Microsoft Fluent Design transparency with CSS or other tools? I like this design language and want to add some elements to my webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the Github projects that implement Fluent Design in ReactJS:

- [React-UWP](https://github.com/myxvisual/react-uwp)
- [FluentFramework](https://github.com/FluentFramework/)

For example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Theme as UWPThemeProvider, getTheme } from "react-uwp/Theme";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";

export class App extends React.Component<void, void> {
  render() {
    return (
      <UWPThemeProvider
        theme={getTheme({
 themeName: "dark", // set custom theme
 accent: "#0078D7", // set accent color
 useFluentDesign: true, // sure you want use new fluent design.
 desktopBackgroundImage: "http://127.0.0.1:8092/staticimages/jennifer-bailey-10753.jpg" // set global desktop background image
        })}
      >
        <MyComponent />
      </UWPThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

./MyComponent.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "react-uwp/Button";

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component<void, void> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button tooltip="Mini Tooltip" />
    )
  }
}
```

**References**

- [React-UWP Example](https://www.ctolib.com/myxvisual-react-uwp.html)
- [Microsoft Fluent Material](https://codepen.io/simoberny/pen/VWKrxg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library for Reveal Effect in Fluent Design System.
And you need to wait for the `backdrop-filter` CSS supported for background blur effect (Safari and Edge support `-webkit-backdrop-filter`).

https://github.com/d2phap/fluent-reveal-effect

[image]

Comment: Please don't post the same answer to multiple different question, like [you did here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44171246/119775). Instead, consider voting/flagging to close one question as a duplicate of the other.